# Can I define multiple events in one Trigger declaration in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here is my requirement, 
I have a mysql table on which any change (insert/delete/update) should be handled in exactly same way. According to mysql documentation create trigger syntax is as follows:

```
    CREATE
     [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
     TRIGGER trigger_name
     trigger_time **trigger_event**
     ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
     trigger_body
```

When I'm trying to put more than one event, its throwing syntax error.
One solution is I can write one procedure and 3 triggers (one for each event) and call the same procedure from all the triggers.

Is there any sophisticated solution for this ??

Answer (score 9):

No. In MySQL, a trigger is for a single trigger_event. A trigger has to be either `BEFORE` or `AFTER` and one of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

If we have lots of logic that is shared across the trigger events (logic that would need to be duplicated in multiple triggers), we can write/create a PROCEDURE to encapsulate that logic, and call that procedure from the body of multiple triggers.