# Multiple events in one MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to monitor multiple events on one table using MYSQL trigger. When these events happened, I can do something on this database. Codes below can accomplish this task:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists trigger_sample1;;  
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sample1  
after UPDATE on table_1 for each row  
begin  
    /* do something */  
end ;; 

DROP TRIGGER if exists trigger_sample2;;  
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sample2  
after INSERT on table_1 for each row  
begin  
    /* do something */  
end ;; 

DROP TRIGGER if exists trigger_sample3;;  
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sample3  
after DELETE on table_1 for each row  
begin  
    /* do something */  
end ;;
```

But I wish to combine these triggers into one trigger. I tried some code like:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists trigger_sample;;  
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sample  
after UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE on table_1 for each row  
begin  
    /* do something */  
end ;;
```

This can not work.I also tried:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists trigger_sample;;  
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sample  
after UPDATE on table_1  
after INSERT on table_1  
after DELETE on talble_1  
for each row  
begin  
    /* do something */  
end ;;
```

This neither work. Is there some advice?

Comment: I dont think its possible, each trigger should be associated with one event

Comment: Advice is to follow what is allowed. The one you are looking is a *custom feature* and is not supported.

Comment: No. The fact that you're doing same things for different events means nothing in terms of triggers. They are different events - so they should be different triggers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I define multiple events in one Trigger declaration in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525674/can-i-define-multiple-events-in-one-trigger-declaration-in-mysql)